# unpack tuples returns wrong result

Tags: python, tuples

```
def search(T, num):
    **#TODO: Your code goes here
    for j in range(len(T)):
        if num==T[j]:
            found=True
            i=j
        else:
            found=False
            i="None"
    return found,i
    pass**

T = (257, 462, 18, 369, 415, 994, 541, 752, 78, 895, 0, 576, 40, 552, 438, 605, 54, 296, 433, 986, 685, 651, 523, 855, 777, 437, 65, 360, 265, 858, 260, 819, 586, 358, 860, 250, 531, 7, 801, 259, 155, 376, 374, 828, 475, 62, 52, 184, 186, 283, 643, 86, 472, 267, 692, 750, 948, 683, 452, 770, 322, 492, 871, 360, 88, 883, 764, 288, 383, 411, 679, 90, 857, 802, 974, 403, 798, 990, 475, 260, 289, 438, 873, 779, 895, 939, 462, 469, 183, 520, 366, 267, 896, 732, 303, 754, 195, 949, 546, 180)

x = int(input("Enter a number to search for in T: "))

# unpacking returned tuple
found, i = search(T, x)
print(found,i)

if found:
    print("First instance found at index {:}".format(i))
else:
    print("{} was not found in T".format(x))


----------
Enter a number to search for in T: 777
False None
777 was not found in T
```

I look for a number which does exist in the tuple, why it still returns not found?
Can you look at the to-do part for me?

Comment: I think you're missing the first line: `def search(T, num):`?

Comment: The problem is that your for loop does not stop when finding the right index. Try adding break under i=j in your if condition

Comment: oh I forgot to copy paste it...thats not the problem...

Comment: Thank you Matina, now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def search(tup, num):
    if num in tup:
        return True, tup.index(num)
    else:
        return False, None
```

note you don't actually need to return the tuple, just return `tup.index(num)` or `None` and then check if the result is `None`.

Comment: That's very readable, but it needlessly searches through the tuple twice. (Once for `num in tup` and once for `tup.index(num)`.)

Comment: Efficiency vs understandability @Aran-Fey ;) I realise that a `try except` is better but didn't want to introduce it unneeded to a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is a coding tutorial since there is a built in function to do this?

The the problem in your code is that you are not breaking out of the loop when you found a match, so unless the match is in the final place you will not see it as the very next else statement will overwrite your answer. Modify your loop as follows:

```
for j in range(len(T)):
    if num==T[j]:
        return True,j

return False, "None" # or better still the keyword None (no quotes)
```

Answer (score -1):

Once found, return the `found` and `i` . You are iterating through whole tuples.
That's the problem.

As per your case, if you give the last element in the tuple in search, you will get the expected result.